# Calculating autocorrelation in spark via sparklyr generates inconsistent results

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I am trying to calculate the autocorrelation within one column of a spark dataframe using sparklyr and `spark_apply()` using the following code snippet.

```
# Read raw data
sdf_raw <- spark_read_parquet(sc = sc, name = "sdf_raw", paste0(root_path, "sdf_raw_clean"))

# Get subset containing only relevant column and cache the result
t <- sdf_raw %>% select(src_ssn) %>% repartition(1) %>% compute("subset")

# Apply acf function via spark_apply
q <- spark_apply(t, function(data) {
  tmp = acf(data$src_ssn, lag.max = 10, plot = F)
  res = data.frame(acf = tmp$acf, lag = seq(0, length(tmp$acf)-1))
  res
})

# Collect the result
e <- q %>% collect()
```

The desired result would be something like

```
            acf lag
1   1.000000000   0
2   0.091755960   1
3   0.043182701   2
4   0.012342259   3
5  -0.009166059   4
6  -0.020663184   5
7  -0.026083233   6
8  -0.026233158   7
9  -0.021264385   8
10 -0.014011600   9
11 -0.009580071  10
```

However, the resulting spark dataframe contains additional rows repeating the lag sequence

```
# A tibble: 3,201 x 2
         acf   lag
       <dbl> <int>
 1  1            0
 2  0.0993       1
 3  0.0448       2
 4  0.00947      3
 5 -0.00656      4
 6 -0.0122       5
 7 -0.0198       6
 8 -0.00980      7
 9 -0.000583     8
10 -0.0148       9
11 -0.0234       10
12  1            0
13 -0.4          1
14 -0.53         2
# … with 3,191 more rows
```

I assumed this has something to do with the partitioning of the data between executors. However, repartitioning `t` to a single partition using `repartition(1)` has not solved the problem. Is this something that is not possible this way or is it something I am doing wrong?